# Android-Align 2 imageViews

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem aligning two imageviews on the same line. I want that one of the imageviews (`imageyourfriends`) to be aligned on the left, while the other (`imageyourfriendrequests`) to be on the right. 
I have been trying different methods but none of them works.
I have this code so far (but one of my imageview is below the other)

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageyourfriends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#AF3800"
            android:src="@drawable/your_friends" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageyourfriendrequests"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#AF3800"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/friend_requests" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#EE6A27"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas/tips what I have to change to get the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageyourfriends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            alignParentLeft="true" // add this
            android:background="#AF3800"
            android:src="@drawable/your_friends" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageyourfriendrequests"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:background="#AF3800"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageyourfriends" // Add this
            android:src="@drawable/friend_requests" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#EE6A27"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first one add "alignParentLeft=true" and for the second one "alignParentRight=true".

Answer (score 2):

Set this way,Add  **`android:layout_alignParentLeft="true`"** and  **`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`** and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` .
So finally, update your ImageView Section,Like:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageyourfriends"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AF3800"
    android:src="@drawable/faleavatar"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageyourfriendrequests"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:background="#AF3800"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/faleavatar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:background="#AF3800"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageyourfriends"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageyourfriendrequests"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#EE6A27"
        android:background="#AF3800"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

in first imageview and

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

in second imageview and also use the

```
android:layout_alignBottom="put the id of first imageview here"
```

android:layout_alignBottom aligns the bottom of two imageviews 
keep in mind that these attributes work inside the relative layout so use relative layout for this